# How can I plant Little Bluestem seeds into burned out turf?

Tags: lawn, overseeding, meadow

We are converting an area of turf to meadow. The plan is to kill off the lawn grasses and seed in a number of warm season grasses and forbs.

The Little Bluestem (*Schizachyrium scoparium*) seed is fluffy and we are concerned that it might not work in a standard lawn slit seeder. There are not a lot of rental options here, so we are wondering if the standard slit seeder can be made to work or if, perhaps, a dethatcher can be used somehow.

Is it possible to do this without specialized equipment?